# How do I add SQL data + hardcoded data to a data model class for binding in a combo box?

Tags: c#, uwp, combobox, datamodel

I have client names in a combo box which is bound by sql data. I need to add another client in the combo box called "New Client". I know how to do this using datasets, but not sure how to here. I need to add a new instance of the Client data model class with "new client" and ID = -1.

I have tried creating a method that creates a "new client" but it always overwrites the SQL data, I need to somehow merge the new client into the data that has been set by SQL.

```
Code to get SQL data into the Client data model. 

    var clients = new ObservableCollection<Client>();
                try
                {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new   SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            cmd.CommandText = "select CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_NAME, EMAIL, ADDRESS_LINE_1, ADDRESS_LINE_2, ADDRESS_LINE_3, ADDRESS_LINE_4, POSTCODE, TELEPHONE_NUMBER from CLIENT";


                            {
                                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                                {
                                    while (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        var client = new Client
                                        {
                                            clientID = reader.GetInt32(0),
                                            clientName = reader.GetString(1),
                                            clientEmail = reader.GetString(2),
                                            add1 = reader.GetString(3),
                                            add2 = reader.GetString(4),
                                            add3 = reader.GetString(5),
                                            add4 = reader.GetString(6),
                                            postcode = reader.GetString(7),
                                            telephoneNumber = reader.GetString(8)
                                        };
                                        clients.Add(client);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return clients;
                }
            }
```

Code to add the "New Client":

```
  public ObservableCollection<Client> newClientRow()
    {
        var clients = new ObservableCollection<Client>();

        var client = new Client
        {
            clientID = -1,
            clientName = "New Client",
            clientEmail = "f",
            add1 = "f",
            add2 = "R",
            add3 = "l",
            add4 = "F",
            postcode = "f",
            telephoneNumber = "01244"
        };

        clients.Add(client);

        return clients;
    }
```

Code to bind the data to the combo box:

```
public ObservableCollection<Client> Source
    {
        get
        {

            daClient daClient = new daClient();
            newClientRow();
            return daClient.GetClients((App.Current as App).ConnectionString);

        }
    }
```

I only get the data that was created from SQL, I need the "new client" to merge in.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

I was getting confused thinking it was the data model class that stores the data but its the ObservableCollection.

All I needed to do was create a new variable of ObservableCollection inside the databinding function. With the variable I added all the SQL data to the collection and then used the .Add function to add a new instance of the Client data model class (which contains "New Client") to the collection. You can then return that collection for use in the combo box.

There is also a very simple way for this to be coded. Which you can see in the updated code.

Also in the function to create the "new client" I had to change the return type to the datamodel, that way you can add it to the collection when calling it.

Updated code (Nothing changed in the SQL function)

Create the new Client data:

```
 private Client newClientRow()
    {
        var clients = new ObservableCollection<Client>();

        var client = new Client
        {
            clientID = -1,
            clientName = "New Client",
            clientEmail = "f",
            add1 = "f",
            add2 = "R",
            add3 = "l",
            add4 = "F",
            postcode = "f",
            telephoneNumber = "01244"
        };
        return client;
    }
```

Add the new client data and sql data to the collection for binding:

```
 public ObservableCollection<Client> Source
    {
        get
        {   
            daClient daClient = new daClient();
            ObservableCollection<Client> clients = new ObservableCollection<Client>(daClient.GetClients((Application.Current as App).ConnectionString))
            {
                //This works the same as using clients.Add(newClientRow()); - just put it inside the curly bracked when initializing the ObservableCollection. 
                newClientRow()
            };
            return clients;
        }
    }
```